# array.splice is not a function - angular

Tags: arrays, angular, function, element, splice

I am trying to delete an element /the last element from an array in angular. This is what `a` looks like

```
0: {geometry: {…}, symbol: {…}, attributes: {…}, infoTemplate: null, _suspended: false, …}
1: {geometry: {…}, symbol: {…}, attributes: null, infoTemplate: null}
2: {geometry: {…}, symbol: {…}, attributes: null, infoTemplate: null}
```

this is my function

```
_pushAddOperation: function (a) {
            console.log("a",a);
            m.forEach(
                a,
                d.hitch(this, function (a) {
                    var b = a.attributes || {};
                    b[this._objectIdName] = this._objectIdCounter++;
                    a.setAttributes(b);
                    this._graphicsLayer.add(a);
                    if (b  === x) {
                        //deletion
                        a.splice(-1,1);
                    }
                })
            );
        }
```

I am getting an error saying a.splice is not a function and I don't understand why

```
_pushAddOperation: function (a) {
            console.log("a",a);
            m.forEach(
                a,
                d.hitch(this, function (k) {
                    var b = a.attributes || {};
                    b[this._objectIdName] = this._objectIdCounter++;
                    k.setAttributes(b);
                    this._graphicsLayer.add(k);
                    if (b  === x) {
                        //deletion
                        k.splice(-1,1);
                    }
                })
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a function `_pushAddOperation` that receive a parameter called `a` (array), but whiting this function you are declaring a new function that receive a parameter called `a`(object) again. So you are actually trying to use `splice` for this object

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly you are saying I should use another name for the second `a` variable? I've edited my question above.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `a` variables, one in the outer function and one in the inner function.  The `a` you are trying to splice appears to be an object.  Not sure, since I don't know what the `hitch` method takes.